# how to make API call with stored token and secret in OAuth 2.0 Php

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

How to access linkedIn connections with stored token and secret. I am using OAuth2.0 and storing the token to databse.  When I tried to make a call with token error returning as '*The request token used hasn't been authorized by user.*' anyone knows the reason??

Comment: Are you trying to access profile data of a user who has not yet authorized your app to do so?

Comment: No. I tried with authorized user tokens..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you must make sure that the token was requested and authorized by the user including the `r_network` scope. Then you can use the equivalent of:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections
```

So:

```
$token = "xxxx";
$url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections";

$headers[0] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Comment: check the request/response, especially the HTTP status, with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true)`

Comment: curl response "[http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.218 [namelookup_time] => 0.171 [connect_time] => 0.218"

Comment: what is the output using `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to `true`? http_code 0 suggests that you have a typo in the URL